# How to return zipcodes that are within a shapefile on QGIS

Tags: qgis

Really new to QGIS and I have made two shapefile layers. One is a shapefile layer of all the zipcodes in the U.S and another is a random shape. How can i get all the zipcodes that are within the boundaries of the random shape and exported into a csv or excel?

[image]

Comment: This document may help https://docs.qgis.org/2.14/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/plugins_spatial_query.html

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Answer (score 1):

Use the Clip tool with the zipcode layer as the input layer and the random shape as the clip layer. Once the clipped shapefile is generated you can copy and paste its attributes into excel.